# how to make form on top

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a problem on making `form2` always on top.

by its property `TopTost=True` truly it will be on top, top meaning top on all applications in my pc. but I only wanted it to be on top oh the `MainForm`

one way is `.ShowDialog` this gives messagebox effect. but that's not quite what I am looking for, I also need to have control on the `MainForm` to put it simple, I want `form2` something like and overlay to display something..

how can I make it so that `form2` is always on top of `MainForm` and only there. if `MainForm` minimizes, it will too.
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for an [owned form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.ownedforms%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Code in `MainForm` class:

```
' Create form to be owned 
Dim ownedForm As New form2()

' Add form2 to the array of owned forms for MainForm (Me)
Me.AddOwnedForm(ownedForm)

' Show the owned form
ownedForm.Show()
```

`form2` will stay on top of `MainForm` until you close it and when/if you minimize `MainForm`, the owned form (`form2`) will minimize along with it.

Comment: can't I put a similar code to `Form2`? because I am using many `Form2` code instances and I think I will have some errors regarding their names and different instances. can't really insert that simply there. thanks

Comment: oh, silly me, got it to work I guess, just added `Me.AddOwnedForm(f)` after the new instance. but if you have something similar code that can be put in `Form2` that would be great! cheers!

Comment: From the description of your scenario, you want `MainForm` to always be the owner, so there is really no reason to have `form2` have this code or am I misunderstanding your question? Glad you got it working, feel free to up-vote the answer as well. :-)

Comment: nah, this is just what I need, I just first thought as `Me.Parent=MainForm` will work at `Form2`'s side. but it did not. lol from what I am thinking now, I just want `Form2` when called is automatically an owned form. no declarations needed. but this seems ok for now :)

Comment: Instead of `Me.Parent = MainForm` you have to use `Me.Owner = MainForm`.

Comment: @AdorableVB - right, as abto said you can use the `Owner` property of `form2` to point to `MainForm`.